# Why everytime I press backspace key in Photoshop the whole layer or the highlighted layer will delete not the text I want to erase

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Example the 20px I want to erase this, but when I press backspace key the highlighted layer will be deleted.

How can i fix this. TIA for the Answers

Comment: On your screenshot it seems that the field is selected but what's inside — isn't, I can't reproduce this. Normally you click in the field, what's there is selected and you press the Delete key

Comment: … or just click & start typing. I've never seen the box selected but not the contents, unless you do a second click to place the cursor specifically.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question, delete key is wrong. Rather when I pressed backspace key

Comment: I think this is probably one for Adobe support. It would probably need a specific OS, setup or app version to repro.

Comment: Like I need to contact adobe support for this problem?

Comment: You probably need to contact Adobe. I can't reproduce this problem either.

Comment: I don't think this is a support issue. I think it's a matter of app familiarity. The behavior described is *standard* and *expected* if the focus is *not* in a panel field (control bar merely being a different shaped panel, but still a panel.)

Answer (score 2):

The **cursor** *must* be **inside** the `size` field to delete what is inside the `size` field. The outer glow highlight for the field, as in your sample, is not enough. The outer glow highlight occurs when you use the drop down menu to change sizes to indicate that's where a change will occur, but it does **not** move the focus to *inside* the field.

In your sample, the `20px` is *inside* the field, you **must** place the cursor into that field (so it's blinking) to delete anything inside the field. If you fail to do this, the *layer* which is highlighted in the Layers panel will be deleted.

It's a matter of *focus* for the app. The app will delete what is currently in focus. If a field does not have focus (i.e. the cursor blinking inside it) then the app assumes the focus is the highlighted *layer* in the Layers Panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you activated the layer but haven't clicked inside the layer to edit the type, and you hit the backspace key, it will delete the layer.

Here are 2 layers, one with a blue background and one with type:

[image]

With the type layer active, and I *click in the type layer* to edit it by using backspace key, the type is erased:

[image]

But if I only have the layer active with no cursor inside the layer to edit, and hit the backspace key, the layer is deleted:

[image]

Make sure not only is the layer active, but you have the type cursor active in the layer. Otherwise, the backspace key will act as a delete key.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-bugs/p-backspace-key-deletes-layers-photoshop-22-5-windows/idc-p/12338107#M22039), roll back to a previous version; or since that thread is from a year ago, update your Photoshop and hope they have fixed it since.